# Take out part of a char array and turn it into a string - Java

Tags: java, string, char, type-conversion

In Java, is there a premade method that I can use to take some selected indices of an array of chars, stick the terms defined by those indices together and return it as a string? The reason I'm looking for a method here is that I would like to avoid having to create another array to hold my selected values. What I'm looking for is something that looks like this:

```
public String charArrayToString(char[] array, int startingIndex, int lastIndex) {
        // ignore any index that is outside of the startingIndex - lastIndex range
        // turn array[startingIndex], array[startingIndex + 1] ... array[lastIndex] into a string
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would use the constructor

```
public String charArrayToString(char[] array, int startingIndex, int lastIndex) {
    return new String(array, startIndex, lastIndex - startIndex + 1);
}
```

Depending on what you are doing with the result, a better solution might be to use StringBuilder.append

```
char[] coords = "000175001022".toCharArray();

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("( ");
sb.append(coords, 0, 6);
sb.append(", ");
sb.append(coords, 6, 6);
sb.append(" )");
System.out.println(sb); // prints ( 000175, 001022 )
```

Comment: I think you need a +1 here as the question appears to want to *include* lastIndex.

Answer (score 7):

Sounds like you want:

```
return new String(array, startingIndex, lastIndex + 1 - startingIndex);
```

... having done some bounds checks on `startingIndex` and `lastIndex`, e.g.

```
startingIndex = Math.max(startingIndex, 0);
lastIndex = Math.min(lastIndex, array.length - 1);
if (startingIndex > lastIndex) {
    // Return empty string? Throw an exception?
}
return new String(array, startingIndex, lastIndex + 1 - startingIndex);
```

Note that if you made your upper bound *exclusive* instead - as most Java APIs are - you could get rid of a lot of these +1 and -1 bits.

Comment: The last parameter is the count, rather than the end like substring ;)

Comment: @AmitD: I prefer to validate the arguments within the methods themselves, as then you can give clearer messages. But yes.

Comment: I guess this If would be sufficient same check from new String method -`if (startingIndex >= 0 && 0 <= lastIndex && lastIndex <= array.length - startingIndex) {return string} else{return error }`

Answer (score 0):

```
public StringBuilder append(char str[], int offset, int len) {
```

Comment: Can you add an example of how you would use this method?

Comment: This would be the best option if the OP wants to add the result to a string.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: Now who cares Jon Skeet has answered the question :)

Comment: Jon Skeet often answers questions, but you can still get some reputation. ;)